# conversion div id haml seems to be changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application running for many years.

Now i find the development version seems to be broken although i did not change anything.

The view works with haml.

In the past the haml code

```
- @id = "test"
#div{ id => "test"} 
#div{ id => @id}
```

Translated to html as

```
<div id='div_test'></div>
<div id='div_test'></div>
```

Now the code translates to

```
<div id='div_test'></div>
<div id='test_div'></div>
```

So if i put the value in a variable the _div is put at the end.

I find this not logic behaviour.

What have i missed ?

My development system is a windows 10 machine.

Rails 4.2.11.3

Comment: This feels like undocumented behavior. With Haml, "#" sets an ID, but this code is also setting an ID in the options hash. I wouldn't be able to guess how that would play out and I'm not surprised that it changed.

Comment: So, have i done something wrong in my code ? should i replace all my #div{ id: .... }  with what ?  I need to set variable in the div.

Comment: I would remove both pound signs and set the ID in the hash, with the variable if needed. You won't have the "div_" or "_div", but it's not clear to me why you'd want that.

Comment: I have changed my code from #div  to %div is this what you mean ? I am not sure why i used #div in the past.

Comment: Yes. With "%" the code won't have competing ideas about what the ID should be.